# type does not conform to protocol Sequence Type - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire, swifty-json

From my `swift` app I'm fetching data from a webservice. 
Data comes as an array:

```
{"hashtags": ["first", "second"]}
```

I want to put every hashtag in a separate row of my `UITableView`. I have the logic to do that, but first - I'm getting werid error while parsing data.

I wrote a custom function:

```
class SingleHashtag: NSObject {

    var hashtagText: [String]

    init(hashtagText: [String]) {
        self.hashtagText = hashtagText
        super.init()
    }

    class func fromJSON(json: JSON) -> SingleHashtag? {
        let hashtagText:[String] = json["hashtags"].arrayValue.map { $0.stringValue}
        return SingleHashtag(hashtagText: hashtagText)
    }
}
```

and then in my main class I have:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "\(serverURL)/hashtags"/*, headers: headers*/)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.description)
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    self.items.removeAllObjects()
                    if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        for hashtag in jsonData {
                            if let userHashtags = SingleHashtag.fromJSON(JSON(hashtag)){
                                for hash in userHashtags {
                                    self.items.addObject(hash)
                                    self.hashtagTable.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    self.hashtagTable.reloadData()
                })
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
```

but this line:

```
for hash in userHashtags {
```

throws an error during compilation:

```
type SingleHashtag does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'
```

I tried adding `as AnyObject` but that didn't help. Can you tell me what might be wrong here?

Comment: `userHashtags` is a `SingleHashtag` and that is not a sequence. Perhaps you meant `for hash in userHashtags.hashtagText {` ?

Comment: Hm I tried that, but now in my method cellForRowAtIndexPath I have a line ` let hash:SingleHashtag = self.items[indexPath.row] as! SingleHashtag` and it throws an error Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x1a0c44378) to 'SingleHashtag' so I'm not sure at what point the parsing in my code is wrong... –

Comment: you said that the data comes in as an array, but you listed a dictionary ({"hastags": ["first", "second", "third"]}) - do you get back an array of those dictionaries? Or do you just get the hashtags dictionary?

Comment: Also - the hashtagText variable for SingleHashtag is an array of strings - did you intend that to be an array - [String] - or just a String? based on your variable and class names, it doesn't feel like you want that to be an array of strings.

Comment: @BJHStudios the response json is exactly like this: `(
        
        hashtags =         (
            test,
            hello, test2
        );
    }
)`

Comment: and what about the hashtagText variable? do you want that to be an array of strings? or just a single string?

Comment: @BJHStudios hm to be honest I think I just named my variables wrong... I want to fetch the data from my webservice (and they come in a format that I pasted above) and display it it in a tableview, where each row is a different hashtag :) Currently I'm getting error mentioned in the 2nd comment here though :(

Comment: You're getting the error because you are trying to run a for loop on an instance of SingleHashtag, which isn't a sequence like an array. But that's just a symptom of the real problem, which is what I'm trying to help you diagnose. How do you define the items array?  is it items: [String] or items: [SingleHashtag]?

Comment: Thanks man :) actually I'm defining it as `var items = NSMutableArray()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on our conversation in the comments it looks like there are lots of things at play here.

Defining `items` as an objective-c object like `NSMutableArray` is fighting against Swift and robbing it of its typing strength. If `items` is only ever a list of hashtag strings, then it should be typed as such. Try changing your items declaration to this:

```
var items = [String]()
```

Based on what you've shared, it also doesn't look like a separate class for `SingleHashtag` is necessary. If it only has one `String` variable, it would be simpler to just pass the strings into items directly. An example of that is here:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "\(serverURL)/hashtags"/*, headers: headers*/)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { response in
        print(response.description)
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                self.items.removeAll()

                //cast the jsonData appropriately, then grab the hashtags
                if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [String: [String]],
                    let hashtags = jsonData["hashtags"] {

                    //hashtags is now type [String], so you can loop
                    //through without the error and add the strings to 'items'
                    for hashtagText in hashtags {
                        self.items.append(hashtagText)
                        self.hashtagTable.reloadData
                    }
                }
            })
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
}
```

Note: this is written in Swift 3, so there will be some syntax differences if you are using an older version of Swift.